# How can I refer to an ng-template using a string?

Tags: angular

I have the following in my angular component.html file:

```html
<nz-collapse *ngFor="let optimization of optimizations; trackBy: trackByTip">
  <nz-collapse-panel [nzHeader]="header" [nzExtra]="optimization.type">
    <ng-template #header>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #HAS_TOO_FEW>
    </ng-template>
  </nz-collapse-panel>
</nz-collapse>
```

The value of `optimization.type` in this case is a string. As I loop through each item (`optimization`), I want the appropriate template, if available, to be referenced. For this case, `optimization.type` yields string `"HAS_TOO_FEW"` which should refer to the `#HAS_TOO_FEW` template. How can I get the string to refer to the template this way?

Note that if a template doesn't exist for the corresponding `optimization.type`, I want the value to be effectively `[nzExtra]="null"`.

I'm very new to Angular so if my entire approach is wrong or not idiomatic, please suggest a different approach. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you want https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Comment: @AlexK That seems close but I have to ultimately use it to set the value of the `[nzExtra]` attribute, whereas the docs there seem to say the switch is for controlling child elements?

Comment: So `[nzExtra]` expects a `TemplateRef`?

Comment: I think so, the library documentation for it is here: https://ng.ant.design/components/collapse/en#components-collapse-demo-extra

Comment: If you insist on it being an attribute, make your own structural directive. Otherwise ngSwitch is the way to go.

Comment: @inorganik It's not that I insist on it being an attribute. That's how it is designed to work as far as I know. I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) to select various templates based on the value of `optimization.type`.

If you wrap that whole NgSwitch chunk in an `<ng-template>` block, you can pass that in as a TemplateRef input.

```html
<nz-collapse *ngFor="let optimization of optimizations; trackBy: trackByTip">
    <nz-collapse-panel [nzHeader]="header" [nzExtra]="optimizationTypeTemplate">

        <ng-template #header>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #optimizationTypeTemplate>
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="optimization.type">
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'HAS_TOO_FEW'">
                    Too few!!
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'HAS_TOO_MANY'">
                    Too many!!
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                    This is the null case
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-template>

    </nz-collapse-panel>
</nz-collapse>
```